# Rails unobtrusive javascript (UJS) ajax:before append data params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I'm trying to append some parameters to a form before sending via ajax (via Rails UJS).

```
  $(document).on("ajax:before",".form-example", function(event) {
    event.data = $(":hidden").serialize();
  });
```

The hidden inputs aren't within the form, so I need to collect them, serialize the, and add them to the request (which is a `PUT` request). However, in the above example, no parameters are being passed to the server, am I doing something wrong? How can I pass parameter called `"items"` with the serialized values of hidden inputs?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to 1) add an empty hidden field (call it A) to the form, 2) intercept the click event of the submit button submitting the form, 3) in the click event add the serialised values of other hidden inputs to field A and allow the ajax submit to continue....

Comment: Thanks mccannf, I might do that. I was just hoping there's a way with Ajax:before

Answer (score 1):

Looking into this, it is actually possible to do, but you do not use the event, you modify the form itself (using `$(this)`).

So something like this could work:

```
$(document).on("ajax:before",".form-example", function() {
  var form = $(this);
  form.append($('<input />',{name: 'hidden_values',value: $(":hidden").serialize()}));
});
```

And you should be able to access the data in your rails action using `params[:hidden_values]`.

Comment: While this works, you can't just modify the settings variable? Was hoping for a cleaner solution.